# Check Json object with string comparison in angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, treeview, children

what i am trying to achieve is to show and element only if an children's value within a JSON object is equal to an string like '[]'.

I am having Json object mytree.currentNode value as

```
{
  "Name": "Three Numbers",
  "ParentId": "3",
  "children": [],
  "selected": "selected"
}
```

i show the information and i do something like:

```
<span ng-show="mytree.currentNode.children == '[]'">Selected Item: {{mytree.currentNode.Name}}</span>
```

But it is not checking the 'children' value is equal to "[ ]"

Thanks in advance

Comment: But the `children` value inside the JSON is not the string `"[]"`, it is an array `[]`. Are you sure you didn't want `mytree.currentNode.children.length == 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"children": []` is not string `'[]'` its an array , so check an empty array like

```
mytree.currentNode.children.length == 0
```

Comment: but one issue i notice is , if `"children": ""` the length will give 0